# zsh path autocomplete does not work in python -m command

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I cannot autocomplete paths in a command like:

```bsh
python -m scripts.really_cool_script path/to_very_important.txt
```

Is it possible to make autocomplete work here?

It's also useful when I want to find the path of the script first, and then edit the command to sub `/` with `.`:

```bsh
python -m scripts/really_cool_script.py
```